# How to create website in Indian language - Kannada

Tags: php, content-management-system, multilingual

I wanted to build a website which would have two versions. **English, Indian Language (Kannada)**.
The website should have same design, creatives , structure and data across the whole site.

This site is **content heavy** and needs a **cms** and a relevant **language editor**. I am a php coder and I am okay with any of the free cms present - wordpress, drupal , joomla. I have heard of installing fonts onto my shared server to support Kannada language. These fonts I guess should support all platforms (windows,mac,linux and mobile website.)

Can anyone please help me on this. Are there any free widgets, plugins which could be installed on my shared server and help display my website in intended languages.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla has the joomfish plugin. It's good and extensive. It's worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

You should set correct charset for your language and I think utf-8 will work for you

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

at top of your script

Answer (score 0):

you can use typeface.js for English, Indian Langauge (Kannada) 
easy and nice one! [get your typeface.js](http://typeface.neocracy.org/)

Comment: For this again I need to download the required font onto my machine is it? And I beleive this would help me in using UNICODE set.

Answer (score 0):

Hi long back i have done kannada website in php , i used define for menu and non-dynamic stuffs in website, and what ever data  is going to inserted in to DB convert them to "entities"

you can use this function

```
function ascii_to_entities($str)
{
    $count  = 1;
    $out    = '';
    $temp   = array();

    for ($i = 0, $s = strlen($str); $i < $s; $i++)
    {
        $ordinal = ord($str[$i]);

        if ($ordinal < 128)
        {
            /*
                If the $temp array has a value but we have moved on, then it seems only
                fair that we output that entity and restart $temp before continuing. -Paul
            */
            if (count($temp) == 1)
            {
                $out  .= '&#'.array_shift($temp).';';
                $count = 1;
            }

            $out .= $str[$i];
        }
        else
        {
            if (count($temp) == 0)
            {
                $count = ($ordinal < 224) ? 2 : 3;
            }

            $temp[] = $ordinal;

            if (count($temp) == $count)
            {
                $number = ($count == 3) ? (($temp['0'] % 16) * 4096) + (($temp['1'] % 64) * 64) + ($temp['2'] % 64) : (($temp['0'] % 32) * 64) + ($temp['1'] % 64);

                $out .= '&#'.$number.';';
                $count = 1;
                $temp = array();
            }
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```

or define method

```
define('lang','ಕನ್ನಡ');
```

link -http://www.jayashomeshop.com/?language=kn